# What exactly do x and z values represent in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The Verilog standard defines four types of bit values: 0, 1, x, and z where 0 means low, 1 means high, x means unknown, and z means an undriven net.

A couple of questions:

1. Does x mean that we don't know if the value is 0 or 1? 0 or 1 or z? or that the value is just unknown and can be something else than 0, 1, or z?
2. Since z represents an undriven net, can a `reg` type have a z bit? If so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, x means that we don't know if the value is 0 or 1.  I suppose it could also include z.  I don't think it ever means anything other than 0/1/z.

x in simulation often means that the signal was not initialized to a 0 or a 1.  This common if you are modeling a flip-flop without a reset.

Another common reason for an x is when a net is driven by multiple drivers (contention).  If one is driving a 0 and the other a 1, the result is x.

Yes, a `reg` can have the value z.  It is common to use procedural assignments to a `reg`.  Here is a simple example of a tri-state driver:

```
module tb;

reg en = 0;
reg out;

always @* out = en ? 1 : 'z;

initial begin
    $monitor($time, " en=%b out=%b", en, out);
    #5 en = 1;
    #5 en = 0;
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
               0 en=0 out=x
               5 en=1 out=1
              10 en=0 out=z
```

This could also be modeled using a continous assignment:

```
wire out = en ? 1 : 'z;
```

In both cases (`reg` and `wire`), the z means the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The value `X` means a number of things depending on what kind of signal you are referring to and how it got that value.

For a *variable* with a 4-state data data type, X is the default initial state, meaning its value is *unknown* and has the potential to be any value. This is a symbolic state as real hardware will be in a particular state 0 or 1 at any specific point in time.
You can also assign variable to the value X because of some operation that you either *don't-care* what its value is, or want to consider that operation illegal. Synthesis tools use that *don't-care* information when optimizing your logic and it will produce deterministic logic.

Nets have values that are a resolution functions of one or more drivers or continuous assignments. The built-in net types resolves multiple drivers by looking at their drive strengths, highest strengths wins. When there is a conflict between equal strengths driving 0 and 1, a `wire` resolves the conflict with an X value. The absence of any strength is called the `Z` state.

It's possible for a variable to be assigned the X or Z state and have that value drive a net through a continuous assignment. If the wire is being driven with a stronger strength, that strong strength's value prevails.